# How to create NotStartsWith Expression tree

Tags: c#, extension-methods, linq-expressions

I'm using `jqGrid` to display some data to users. jqGrid has search functionality that does string compares like Equals, NotEquals, Contains, StartsWith, NotStartsWith, etc.

When I use `StartsWith` I get valid results (looks like this):

```
Expression condition = Expression.Call(memberAccess,
                typeof(string).GetMethod("StartsWith"),
                Expression.Constant(value));
```

Since DoesNotStartWith doesn't exist I created it:

```
public static bool NotStartsWith(this string s, string value)
{
    return !s.StartsWith(value);
}
```

This works, and I can create a string and call this method like so:

```
string myStr = "Hello World";
bool startsWith = myStr.NotStartsWith("Hello"); // false
```

So now I can create/call the expression like so:

```
Expression condition = Expression.Call(memberAccess,
                typeof(string).GetMethod("NotStartsWith"),
                Expression.Constant(value));
```

But I get a `ArgumentNullException was unhandled  by user code: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: method` error.

Does anyone know why this doesn't work or a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're checking for method `NotStartsWith` on type string, which doesn't exist. Instead of `typeof(string)`, try `typeof(ExtensionMethodClass)`, using the class where you put your `NotStartsWith` extension method. Extension methods don't actual exist on the type itself, they just act like they do.

Edit: Also rearrange your `Expression.Call` call like this,

```
Expression condition = Expression.Call(
            typeof(string).GetMethod("NotStartsWith"),
            memberAccess,
            Expression.Constant(value));
```

The overload you are using expects an instance method, this overload expects a static method, based on the SO post you referred to. See here, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd324092.aspx

Comment: I changed `typeof(string)` to `typeof(MyExtensionClass)` but I get a new error `Static method requires null instance, non-static method requires non-null instance. Parameter name: instance`. This was asked in another thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695235/expression-equals/3695436#3695436 but I don't know how to fix the problem.

Comment: Looking at that post `Expression.Call` is searching the first argument you send for the method info being passed, which won't work because its a static method (non-instance). You have to use a different overload of `Expression.Call`, like this one, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd324092.aspx. Give the method info first, and the two arguments next.

Comment: Thanks for the code example you provided Kratz! `NotStartsWith` works great now. I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

i know the ask was answered, but another approach is available and simple:

```
Expression condition = Expression.Call(memberAccess,
                                       typeof(string).GetMethod("StartsWith"),
                                       Expression.Constant(value));

condition = Expression.Not(condition);
```

and... done! just have to negate the expression.